# Toggle active class on a button but maintain state of other buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've read [Javascript / JQuery Toggle Active Class between 2 buttons on a button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169424/javascript-jquery-toggle-active-class-between-2-buttons-on-a-button-group). However I have a situation where I want to toggle the active class on a button being clicked, but maintain the state of the other buttons.

For example:

```
 <!-- Button 1 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn1" class="filter-btn active">

 <!-- Button 2 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn2" class="filter-btn">

 <!-- Button 3 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn3" class="filter-btn active">

 <!-- Button 4 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn4" class="filter-btn">
```

Button 1 and Button 3 have an `active` class.

If I click Button 1, with the intention of toggling it to being inactive, I want to remove the `active` class on Button 1 *but keep the `active` class on Button 3*.

I can't see how to do this because the following will remove the `active` class on all buttons, then re-apply it to Button 1 when clicked again:

```
$('.filter-btn').on('click', 'input', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

So the end result is that Button 1 has the `active` class removed, which is what I want. But Button 3 also has the `active` class removed, which I don't want.

How is it possible to write this so it only toggles the class on the button clicked and leaves everything else as-is?

Comment: Remove the `.siblings().removeClass('active')` logic and your code will work as you require

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run some conditional work for your input to add and remove class on the input you click:

```js
$( "input" ).click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
   
        if ($this.hasClass("active")) {
            $this.removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Button 1 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn1" class="filter-btn active">

 <!-- Button 2 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn2" class="filter-btn">

 <!-- Button 3 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn3" class="filter-btn active">

 <!-- Button 4 -->
 <input type="button" name="btn4" class="filter-btn">
```

You can check by inspecting the elements of the `inputs` once clicking them that the `active` class would be added and removed if clicked

### Update

If you would like to slim the JavaScript down further, you can use toggleClass():

```
$( "input" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You can replace the `if` condition with a single `toggleClass()` call