# Switch active class between groups of include/exclude buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an application which provides a list of filters.

Each filter has an "include" and "exclude" button, for example:

```
<input type="button" name="include_337" value="+"> 
<input type="button" name="exclude_337" value="-"> Filter 1

<input type="button" name="include_856" value="+"> 
<input type="button" name="exclude_856" value="-"> Filter 2
```

So this renders a `+` (for "include") and `-` (for "exclude") button with the filter name listed beside it. The `name` attribute of the buttons shows whether it is a button to include (`include_`) or exclude (`exclude_`) the filter, followed by an ID number that comes from a database.

When any of the buttons are clicked I place an `active` class on the button. I recently asked about how to toggle those buttons: [Toggle active class on a button but maintain state of other buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661585/toggle-active-class-on-a-button-but-maintain-state-of-other-buttons/48661680)

However, I have a separate issue. If I click, for example, `-` on Filter 1 it will add the `active` class:

```
<input type="button" name="include_337" value="+"> 
<input type="button" name="exclude_337" class="active" value="-"> Filter 1
```

It should not be possible to have the `active` class on both the include and exclude button. However, I'm not sure how to do this. At the moment, it's possible to click the `+` on Filter 1 and both will get the `active` class:

```
<input type="button" name="include_337" class="active" value="+"> 
<input type="button" name="exclude_337" class="active" value="-"> Filter 1
```

What I want is effectively like radio buttons, where it's only possible to have either `+` or `-` active at any one time *for a specific filter*. However these must be button elements, not radio buttons, so I don't want to change the `type` attribute.

I've had a look at [jQuery: Uncheck other checkbox on one checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785010/jquery-uncheck-other-checkbox-on-one-checked) but this is slightly different as it uses radio buttons and also unchecks all other checkboxes. In this case I want it to apply to groups of filters - i.e. **changing Filter 1 should not affect Filter 2**, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: The most logical way to handle this would be a simple checkbox, to either switch a filter on or off ... This sounds like a typical designer-thinks-they-know-best requirement ... (whereas from a user perspective, I would expect buttons showing `+`/`-` to be intended to increase/decrease a numerical value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done here is put each pair inside a div that has a class of `.filterGroup`. This means they are separated from the other groups.

Alongside this, I am then using the `siblings()` function in jQuery to check if a class is found and then remove it. You can see the text changes to `red` once it has the active class.

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.toggleClass("active");

  if ($this.siblings().hasClass("active")) {
    $this.siblings().removeClass("active")
  }
});
```

```css
input.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filterGroup">
  <input type="button" name="include_337" value="+">
  <input type="button" name="exclude_337" value="-"> Filter 1
</div>

<div class="filterGroup">
  <input type="button" name="include_856" value="+">
  <input type="button" name="exclude_856" value="-"> Filter 2
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any significance of `.filterGroup`? I haven't got that, it's just a set of inputs but actually still works. I don't really understand how that's possible - does it target the nearest thing with `.active` or something else?

Comment: @Andy No major significance no, it's just a div to separate the groups you have. The jQuery then looks at the input siblings _inside_ the `.filterGroup` div

Comment: Thanks. I understood that it was to separate them, but it still seems to work when they are just listed as a huge set of `inputs` (all contained inside 1 `div`). So not sure how that works, but it does!

Comment: @Andy The reason it works without the divs is that it looks at all the inputs as siblings, but I assumed you wanted to set multiple filters so just wrapped them in the div :)