# JavaScript - How can I disable and enable more than one Button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

JavaScript

My problem description:

I have two groups of buttons, one group consists of 4 different buttons and the other group consists also of 4 different buttons. With different I mean that the textcontent is different.

ALL TWO GROUPS OF BUTTONS ENABLED

[image: ALL TWO GROUPS OF BUTTONS ENABLED]

If I clicked one button of one group, I want that the other buttons of the group will be disabled so the person can only select one button from the other group.

DISABLED BUTTONS FROM FIRST GROUP IF ONE BUTTON IS SELECTED

[image: DISABLED BUTTONS FROM FIRST GROUP IF ONE BUTTON IS SELECTED]

And if the person clicked first a button of the other group I want that the other buttons are also disabled from the same group.

DISABLED BUTTONS FROM THE SECOND GROUP IF ONE BUTTON IS SELECTED

[image: DISABLED BUTTONS FROM THE SECOND GROUP IF ONE BUTTON IS SELECTED]

And if the person have clicked a button from the first group and from the second group. Than I want that the not selected buttons are enabled, so that the person can select another one from one group.

Important is that the two selected buttons keep disabled, when the other will be enabled.

Can someone say me how to do that?

I created the buttons dynamic with two button clicked events in a for loop.

```js
First button group

button.id = "assign-picture-question-example-" + letter.toLowerCase() + "-btn";
button.className = "example example-" + letter.toLowerCase() + "-btn example-btn btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block";

In the click event:

document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("disabled", true);
$(".example-btn").not(this).each(function() {
  document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("disabled", true);
});

Second button group

button2.id = "assign-picture-question-answer-" + (i + 1) + "-btn";
button2.className = "answer answer-btn answer-" + (i + 1) + "-btn btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block";

In the click event:

document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("disabled", true);
$(".answer-btn").not(this).each(function() {
 document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("disabled", true);
});
```

But now I want that the buttons of the first left group are enabled if the button of the second right group are clicked....and I don't know how...the selected button should be stay disabled. And vice versa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169424/javascript-jquery-toggle-active-class-between-2-buttons-on-a-button-group

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow (at least, for me it is). There's a bit too much _"this group"_ / _"other group"_ to follow what you're saying. Do you think you could be a bit more specific? Perhaps label them "group A", "group B", etc. Even better would be something visual (screenshots, MS paint mockup, ASCII art).

Comment: I added some picture for you ;)

Comment: Can someone help me?